# VCR with Cucumber for Braintree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, braintree, vcr

I am using Cucumber to test Braintree integration (for credit card payments) in a Rails 3.2 app. I am trying to add VCR gem to record the response from Braintree for the specs.

When i run the tagged scenario, it passes and records the cassette.

**Problem**: 
When i rerun to check the use of the recorded cassette, it fails with this message -
`not in gzip format (ActionView::Template::Error)`
on a step immediately after loading the credit card (hosted) fields.

I tried playing around with the cassette option `:decode_compressed_response`, but i am not sure i understand it right.

Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated! :-)

Here's my VCR config (`feature/config/vcr.rb`):

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'features/cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.default_cassette_options = {
    :decode_compressed_response => false
  }
  c.ignore_localhost = true
end

VCR.cucumber_tags do |t|
  t.tag  '@vcr', :use_scenario_name => true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the following line to the `c.default_cassette_options` gets rid of the `not in gzip format` error.
`:serialize_with => :compressed`

This gzips the cassette after recording it in yaml format.

One thing that still puzzles me is why is VCR trying unzip a non-compressed  cassette in the first place... haven't found a setting for that yet.